# Resize center layoutunit in PrimeFaces dyanmically based on content

Tags: layout, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page with a "header", "footer", "side menu" and a "content area".

I'm trying to arrange them using PrimeFaces layouts as follows:

Header -->North

Footer --> South

Side Menu --> East

Content Area --> Center

At a first glance, it's working fine.

However, my side menu contains links that will change the contents of the center area. Currently, when I click one of the links, the center area's contents will change and a vertical scroll bar will appear in the center area if the new contents have a length that is larger than the one defined for the center layoutunit.

The behavior I'm looking for is to resize the center area dynamically, pushing down the footer (south layoutunit) and showing a scroll bar for the whole page.

Is it correct that I'm using PrimeFaces layouts? Should I use something else?

Here is my "body" code:

```
<h:body>

<p:layout fullPage="true">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="200">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="260">
        <ui:include src="side-menu.xhtml" />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <ui:insert name="body-content">
        </ui:insert>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:body>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you are open to dropping `p:layout` I can give an advice.

Comment: @Ömer Faruk Almalı Yes I'm open to anything. Please advise.

Comment: You should check my answer.

Answer (score 6):

> *Is it correct that I'm using PrimeFaces layouts? Should I use something else?*

**Answer**: It depends. I think, `p:layout fullPage="true"` is a component for whom wants to create a page super quick, simple and who does not have enough time with labour with view layer. If the showcase example is corresponding your requirements barely then there is no reason to drop it.

But if you want to customize or change it's behaviour or it's functionality stop and **roll your own.**

I have prepared a kickoff example which suits your requirements, as I said, it is not complete but it can inspire you. Let's start with components;

```
<h:form>
    <p:fieldset legend="West" styleClass="west">

    </p:fieldset>
    <p:panel styleClass="north">

    </p:panel>
    <p:fieldset legend="East" styleClass="east">

    </p:fieldset>
    <p:fieldset legend="Center" styleClass="center">   

    </p:fieldset>

    <p:panel styleClass="footer">
        <p:commandButton onclick="makeMe();" value="SeeTheMagic"></p:commandButton>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

As it can be seen, these are the basic PrimeFaces components, point here CSS's itself. (I've used [p:fieldset](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fieldset.jsf), cause I like it's looknfeel you can use `p:panel` instead).

Let's start with `footer`. There is a thing that deserves to be mentioned, it's position, we are just placing it to bottom of the page via `bottom:0px` and `position:absolute`.

```
.footer{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    padding:30px;
    background: #000007;
    clear: both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Center component is HORIZONTALLY centered by `margin 0 auto`. There are other ways to do surely. Also if you want to center it vertically it is simple to do via margin. And `margin-top:70px` is just preventing overlap with north panel.

```
.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:650px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

East is positioned to most-left and west; vice versa.

```
.east{
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.west{
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

North component is just like the footer but it is on the top of course via `top:0px`.

```
.north {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Now page looks like sth. similar to `p:layout fullPage="true"`. You should customize it's looknfeel of course, maybe you can have a look to newer CSS properties like `box-shadow`(for north panel) or etc. Consequently about your requirement:

> The behavior I'm looking for is to resize the center area dynamically,
>   pushing down the footer (south layoutunit) and showing a scroll bar
>   for the whole page.

I've prepared a content which is initially overflows from center panel and then there is a button on the footer which says sth. about magic and it calls `makeMe()` js function which does:

```
function makeMe() {
    $(".center").css({
        "height":"auto",
        "word-wrap": "break-word"
    });
    $(".footer").css({
        "position":"relative"
    });
}
```

Simply expands the `p:panel`'s height, now if it has 100 content items it will compass all of them. And via `position:relative`, we are saying to footer "don't stay there just stick into bottom of center component."

This is how it looks initially:

[image]

If you are loading your content via ajax there won't be a scrollbar initially. I just copied lot's of text into it that's why there is a scrollbar initially.

After clicking the button:

[image]

If there will be problem just warn me, hope that helps.

Comment: I'm thankful for your efforts. I tried your solution but I'm not getting what I want. It's increasing the size of the center fieldset, but the footer is not appearing. I'll investigate it further later, especially the css manipulation. If it works with me, I'll inform you.

Comment: That's completely working on me. You saying when you click the button footer is not appearing right?